# Backtrack in python but stop going deeper if condition is met

Tags: python, list, backtracking

So I understand the concept of backtracking and looked through the code [here](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/write-a-c-program-to-print-all-permutations-of-a-given-string/) to implement the simple string permutation algorithm.

My problem however is the following:

I have a list of n lists of the form:

```
l = [[1,2,3],[4,3,2],[7,6,5],[1,2,9],[6,8]]
```

Say I sort these lists by least number of occurrence of an element and place in a dictionary where the key represents the number of occurrence of an element, like so:

```
d = {1:[[7,6,5],[6,8],[4,3,2],[1,2,9]], 2:[[1,2,3],[1,2,9],[4,3,2],[7,6,5],[6,8]], 3:[[1,2,3],[4,3,2],[1,29]]}
```

So what that dictionary represents is the following:

- The numbers **4, 5, 7, 8** and **9** occur only once so all lists containing them are put into a list with the key **1**.
- The numbers **1, 3** and **6** occur twice and all lists containing them are put into a list with the corresponding key **2**.
- The number **2** occurs 3 times so all lists containing it are put in a list of lists with key **3**.

Now, in order to find a set cover for these the set of numbers from **1 to 9**, I know I will NEED to use all the list of lists with the key **1**. If this satisfies the entire range from 1 to 9 (in this case it does), my job is done. Otherwise, I will need to backtrack with EACH list in the list of lists corresponding to key **2**, if I find a combination that satisfies, I stop. If none of them satisfy, I move onto the lists corresponding to key **3**.

How would one achieve this in python and is this a good way of implementing it?

I realize the question is hard to explain in plain English so if it's unclear, please let me know.

Comment: This sounds like a massive xy problem. If this is a homework assignment for which you designed an algorithm yourself which you don't want to be helped with beyond this detail, I really respect that and won't pry further. Otherwise, I'd really like to know why you got yourself into this mess? What are you really trying to do?

Comment: This is in fact a hw problem. I'm trying to solve the set cover problem for fairly large data sets as fast as possible as part of a larger assignment. I thought I would be able to code this fairly easily using simple backtracking after sorting the dictionary by key, but its turned out to be harder than I thought.

Comment: Could you edit the larger problem into the question , perhaps as an addendum , if you are willing to accept help in a broader scope than the immediate dictionary issue?

Comment: Also, increasing keys probably shouldn't have repeated lists from lower level keys if I understand what you are trying to do correctly.

Comment: Yes, the idea is to not reconsider any lists that have already been considered but I figured it would be easier to do that later as opposed to when adding them to the dictionary, I suppose I could prune repeated lists out to begin-with.

Comment: And the larger problem is essentially just solving the uni-cost set cover problem optimally as fast as possible. Meaning the solutions can not be approximations. I implement other heuristics to place bounds on my solution size but this is probably the main step to getting me the optimal solution fast as possible.

Comment: You could start with removing each list once it goes in the dictionary. That would immediately solve your pruning problem. If you store the initial list as a `collections.deque`, this should be more efficient (there is no built in linked list type as I found out today)

Comment: I agree, it may be wiser to prune prior to insertion so I will do that. I considered using a deque but I'm not too familiar with deque operations but yes, I will read up on the documentation more thoroughly as that sounds like a better idea.

Comment: `deque` presents an interface just like a list as far as you are concerned, but it will be much faster for removals.